# A Sci-fi book where a man is abandoned on a planet where the majority of inhabitants don't eat animals or plants or anything that was once alive?

Tags: story-identification, novel

It's a twentieth century or possibly older book by an author who's relatively unknown. In the first chapter, there is a summoning of a spirit or something of that sort. Later, he is abandoned on a planet where he meets a married woman who transfers some of her blood since his is incompatible to the planet's atmosphere? The protagonist then meets a fisherman who kind of helps him and whose wife leaves with him. Then they meet a man who plays and will continue playing a musical instrument of some kind for all eternity. Also, the protagonist is in search of a local spirit or god or something similar.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Having a time period of multiple centuries makes it a little difficult to narrow down. Do you know maybe a more specific period of it's age? Or when you may have read it.

Comment: I am so sorry! I was searching for it on behalf of my girlfriend who just found it. A Voyage to Arcturus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[A Voyage to Arcturus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Voyage_to_Arcturus) by David Lindsay.

The book begins with a seance in which an apparition is materialized. The protagonist travels to a planet named Tormance where a woman named Joiwind exchanges blood with him. The planet is divided into regions, and the inhabitants of one of the regions don't eat animals or plants.
But the protagonist isn't abandoned on the planet, he travels to it in search of something.

The book plays out the story of a man named Maskell as he traverses through the many regions that make up the planet Tormance, with each region signifying a specific perspective on life.

Comment: It would help if you could add quotes or a synopsis as to *why* this fits the description. Also, after 48 hours you can accept your own answer which would help keep the site tidy for possible future questions.